# Open url in browser, from shell script on android

Tags: android, shell, browser

I need to open url from shell script on android, in lightning or at least in default browser. To open browser I use following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
monkey -p  acr.browser.barebones -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

*This is not duplicate as I need not only default browser.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a URL from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488179/how-to-open-a-url-from-terminal)

Comment: One more question, how to make it work from not root shell?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: When running `monkey -p  acr.browser.barebones -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1` not from root shell - it not working

Comment: what error did you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open url monkey not needed:

```
root@dolphin-fvd-p1:/opt/etc # cat OpenURL                                                                      
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$PATH

am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d $1 acr.browser.barebones
```

To start browser on home page:

```
root@dolphin-fvd-p1:/opt/etc # cat StartBrowser                                                                 
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$PATH

am start --user 0  acr.browser.barebones
```