# Create new tab in webview

Tags: android, browser, webview

Now I am trying to develep a browser app in android using webview. But I have trouble now, I don't know how to create new tab in webview like the same chrome or firefox or when I click any link, it will open a new tab (new webview).
I am a newbie, please help me. Thanks all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Browser: open several URLs, each on new window/tab (programmatically)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119084/android-browser-open-several-urls-each-on-new-window-tab-programmatically)

Comment: @GabrielOshiro thanks

Answer (score 0):

First write code for adding tabs in your activity, then write references for xml in java file and or creating tabs for webview u can use Tabspec ts=ts.setContent(new Intent(this,webview.class)); to start your webview in that tab.